# Sending an operator as a paramenter in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I have two variables and an operator (could be any of +, - , /, comparison...).
Is it a good idea to write a function that takes 2 arguments and the operator as the parameters?

Function may be something like below

```
T foo(int a,int b, sometype(not sure) operator)
```

and then make a string out of that

```
foo(a,b,+);

as  a+b
```

Would this be a good approach or is there any other approach?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: You cannot pass operators that way so I wouldn't call it a "good approach".

Comment: you might want to use [std::plus](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/plus) or use a lambda, just template your `foo` on the functor type.

Comment: You could use lambda expressions like: `foo(a, b, [](int x, int y) { return x + y;});`

Comment: You can make a template function that will accept some other function, that does addition, as a parameter.

Comment: Anyways that i can send an operator as a parameter  and  then  use it for the parameters sent

Comment: But i would need to have lot of lambda functions for each operator ..isnt it.

Comment: @user2256825 you are still unclear about what do you want to achieve. For some operators there are functions ready, for example, std::plus or std::less, for others you need to write a lambda function. What is "a lot of lamda functions" for you?

Comment: foo(a, b, [](int x, int y) { return x + y;}); is for addition , Same way i think i need it for all the other operators

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't. Operators are special, they are not ordinary functions. (For instance, operators can have short circuit evaluation and have no overload resolution if all operands are built-in types. Functions cannot do that.)

Pass a binary operation object instead, like:

```
template <class BinaryOp>
int fun(int, int, BinaryOP);
```

You can then pass functors like an instance of  `std::plus<>` or binary lambdas<sup>†</sup> as a third argument. This is a common practice in C++.

Note that functors wrapping the built in operators, such as the aforementioned `std::plus`, are readily available in the header [`<functional>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/functional).

---

Sample code for reference:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template <class T>
void fun (int i, int j, T t)  {
    std::cout << t(i,j) << "\n";
}

int main () {
    fun(1,2,std::plus<>{});                      // Or std::plus<int>{} in C++11
    fun(1,2,[](auto i, auto j){return i * j;});  // Again, with explicit types for C++11
}
```

This will print

```
3
2
```

---

<sup>†</sup>As this is tagged C++11: The functors `std::plus<T=void>` etc. as used in this answer are available in C++14 and later. In C++11, you need to provide a template argument like `std::plus<int>`. Same goes for the lambda, which would need to become `[](int i, int j){...}`.

Comment: Can you also post a sample code for binary lambdas,seems to be really advanced stuff

Comment: @user2256825 Done. Again, if for C++11, you need to make the types explicit.

Answer (score 4):

Operators cannot be passed that way, it wouldn't compile: the languages doesn't allow that. You could pass a character that describes the operation to do:

```
template <class T>
T foo(T lhs, T rhs, char op)
{
   switch (op)
   {
       case '+':
                return lhs + rhs;

       // other operators

   }
}
```

Another option is passing a function that does the actual computation as parameter:

```
template <class T, class Operator>
T foo(T lhs, T rhs, Operator op)
{
    return op(lhs, rhs);
}
```

Now you can write your `Operator`s or use the ones already provided: `std::plus`, `std::minus` etc. You find them in `<functional>`.

```
// ...
foo(5, 10, std::plus<int>{})
```

If you want to have your versions of these, write the required callables as lambdas or functions:

```
template <class T>
T add(T lhs, T rhs) { return lhs + rhs; }

foo(5, 10, add<int>);
foo(5, 10, [](int a, int b){ return a + b; }); // or use `auto` to make it generic
```

Comment: Is there a reason for downvoting?

Comment: "The easiest option is passing a character"?

Comment: @Barry Grammar mistake? Feel free to edit, it'd be appreciated. Otherwise, you don't find it to be the easiest way?

Comment: Manually written dispatch tables based off switches (of `char` or whatever) are not easy to get right: they are in fact extremely easy to get wrong, based on how many bugs in them I have run into over the years. They are also a headache to maintain; if you use anything like the above technique in more than one spot in your code, tracking down and fixing all of them when you add another operator is going to take time and care and the copmiler won't help you one bit. "easy", in that a first-year college student might grab it as a "*solution*", but not *easy* as in "less effort in the end".

Comment: @Yakk I've edited a bit. Still, if not easy, it's the first thing that would come to my mind. Templates are no easier to mantain and the compiler will blindly punish you under rows of expansions if you get something wrong; not to mention that for a longstanding solution you'll want to employ some constraints on the callable object. Do I have to know templates, SFINAE/Concepts to solve the originary problem? Either way, I don't find it a reason for downvoting IMO.